# Why does mysql_insert_id() return 0?

Tags: php, mysql

When I run this code

```
$sql_select = "INSERT INTO `database`.`table`(Columns) VALUES (Values)... ";
$mysqlid = mysql_insert_id($sql_select->db);
echo ($mysqlid);
```

I get the error message

```
mysql_insert_id(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link
```

I have tried this variation;

```
$mysqlid = mysql_insert_id();
echo ($mysqlid);
```

but that returns a 0 which, according to the documentation, means an auto_increment field was not found. The only thing I can think of is that I am not calling the auto_increment column in the $sql_select, but there is an auto_increment column in there; will that affect the behavior of mysql_insert_id?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that your data is being inserted correctly?

Comment: You don't appear to have actually run a query.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to actually run the query first:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO `database`.`table`(Columns) VALUES (Values)...";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

and then after that:

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
echo $id
```

Let me know if you have still problems.

Comment: my tables still updates without using mysql_query however, what is the difference between the 2

Comment: mysql_query() actually execute the query. So, if your query executed, you will get the result

Comment: You'd be wise to test whether or not your query was successful

Comment: How could the query not be successful?

Answer (score 4):

That is because `$sql_select->db` is **not** a valid MySQL Link

What you are looking for is something like this:

```
$sql_select = "INSERT INTO `database`.`table`(Columns) VALUES (Values)... 
$result = mysql_query($sql_select);
$mysqlid = mysql_insert_id($result->db);
```

`$result` is a valid MySQL resource.

Also don't forget to have created a [mysql connection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

NOTE: While I used code for the [original MySQL driver](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) it's use is discouraged. Instead you want to use [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Answer (score 2):

You need to run your query:

```
if($result = mysql_query($sql_select)){
    $mysqlid = mysql_insert_id();
    echo $mysqlid;
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

your connection of `mysqli` is an object...so try this....

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "dbname");
```

after inserting try this..

```
echo $mysqli->insert_id;
```