# mysql_insert_id() always returning 0 after successfully inserting the values

Tags: php, mysql

I have defined the column as AUTO INCREMENT.and I have inserted the value into MYSQL database. The values are updated successfully. after inserting i need to get last inserted id. I am using using mysql_insert_id to get the last auto incremented value.But its returning 0 always.

Comment: Could you post your code please?

Comment: have a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163754/why-does-mysql-insert-id-return-0?rq=1